# Kinect installation error

Tags: installation, kinect, kinect-interaction

[image]

i recently brought kinect sensor. As per system requirement i purchase desktop . Now followed installation mentioned bellow link. I also downloaded verification link. when check installation it giving me below error. let me know how to sort it out

i already tried reinstal directx 11 download from Microsoft & restarted computer. but i found in device manager only one [image: device manager] part is detected. kinect sensor information not avilable.

**please let me know what wrong i am doing here**

[install link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/purchase/sensor_setup.aspx) 
[kinect verifier link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/purchase/sensor_setup.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy a faster GPU that supports DX11.

According to:
http://www.game-debate.com/hardware/?gid=326&graphics=GeForce%20210%201GB
http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2297019/play-directx-supported-games-geforce-210.html

your Geforce 210 only supports up to DX 10.1, as is also shown in
your first screenshot as Direct3d API version.

Comment: yes i got it. i am planning to use gt720,730,680 series . but what i can do overcome usb3.0 error.[pc specification](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&dlc=en&docname=c04510232&lc=en&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001)

Comment: I also have an USB3.0 error, but kinect works fine. So it can still work, but I can't garantees.